# Do I have to use synchronized on main thread methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

To be more specific my question is if the main thread methods are already synchronized?
For example:

```
    @MainThread
    class MyClass{
        private Object o = null;

        @MainThread
        MyClass(){
        }

        @MainThread
        public Object getObjectFromMainThread(){
            return this.o.getObj2();
        }

        @MainThread
        public void setObjectFromMainThread(Object obj){
            obj.set(1);
            this.o=obj;
        }

        @AnyThread
        public synchronized Object getObjectFromAnyThread(){
            return this.o;
        }

        @AnyThread
        public synchronized void setObjectFromAnyThread(Object obj){
            this.o=obj;
        }
    }
```

The methods getObjectFromMainThread and setObjectFromMainThread which are called only from main thread are not synchronized. Does it need to be synchronize as well or is not necessary?

Comment: There is nothing magical about the main thread. It has the same synchronization requirements as all the others. You don't need four methods. Two would do: one setter and one getter.

Comment: The code is just for example. The main thread methods and other threads methods are all different. I only want to know if the synchronization is implicit for main thread or for the thread that instantiated the class

Comment: I can only repeat what I just said. There is nothing magical about the main thread, and no reason why you should provide different methods for it and for other threads.

Comment: OffffffffNow they are different

Comment: I only need to know if main thread methods need synchronization as well. Some of you say yes some say no!

Comment: OfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffWhy? Why does one thread get a different result from another thread? There is nothing magical about the main thread, for the third time, unless you are bound and determined to make it so, which you seem to be, for no apparent reason.

Comment: All threads need synchronization to the same extent. For the fourth time, there is nothing magical about the main thread.

Comment: EJP, Your answer makes sense and I think the same but Barend say that the main thread methods does not need synchronization

Comment: @chris No he doesn't. He says that `volatile` objects don't need synchronization. Now that you've changed your question, volatility is no longer relevant. He also says that there is nothing magical about the main thread.

Comment: I removed the volatile, it seems that created too much confusion and deviated from my question. My question is strict about synchronization on main thread methods whatever is the case

Comment: How many times do you need it answered exactly? Your current code doesn't even compile. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Possibly you are looking for `java.util.ThreadLocal` instead of all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your immediate question is yes, you will have to synchronize the `getObjectFromMainThread` and `setObjectFromMainThread` methods in your example. The answer to *why* there's this need is a mighty deep rabbit hole.

The general problem with multithreading is what happens when multiple threads access **shared, mutable state**. In this case, the shared, mutable state is `this.o`. It doesn't matter whether any of the threads involved is the main thread, it's a general problem that arises when more than one thread is in play.

The problem we're dealing with comes down to "what happens when a thread is reading the state at the same time that one or more threads are writing it?", with all its variations. This problem fans out into really intricate subproblems like each processor core having its own copy of the object in its own processor cache.

The only way of handling this is to make explicit what will happen. The `synchronized` mechanism is one such way. Synchronization involves a *lock*, when you use a synchronised method, the lock is `this`:

```
public synchronized void foo() {
    // this code uses the same lock...
}

public void bar() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // ...as this code
    }
}
```

Of all the program code that synchronizes on the same lock, only one thread can be executing it at the same time. That means that if (and only if) all code that interacts with `this.o` runs synchronized to the `this` lock, the problems described earlier are avoided.

In your example, the presence of `setObjectFromAnyThread()` means that you must also synchronize `setObjectFromMainThread()`, otherwise the state in `this.o` is accessed sometimes-synchronized and sometimes-unsynchronized, which is a broken program.

Synchronization comes at a cost: because your locking bits of code to be run by one thread at a time (and other threads are made to wait), you remove some or all of the speed-up you gained from using multi-threading in the first place. In some cases, you're better off forgetting multi-threading exists and using a simpler single-threaded program.

Within a multi-threaded program, it's useful to limit the amount of shared, mutable state to a minimum. Any state that's *not* accessed by more than one thread at a time doesn't need synchronization, and is going to be easier to reason about.

The `@MainThread` annotation, [at least as it exists in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/MainThread.html), indicates that the method is intended to be accessed on the main thread only. *It doesn't do anything*, it's just there as a signal to both the programmer(s) and the compiler. There is no technical protection mechanism involved at run time; it all comes down to your self-discipline and some compile-time tool support. The advantage of this lack of protection is that there's no runtime overhead.

Multi-threaded programming is complicated and easy to get wrong. The only way to get it right is to truly understand it. There's a book called [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://jcip.net/) that's a really good explanation of both the general principles and problems of concurrency and the specifics in Java.

Comment: You say that "The synchronized mechanism avoids some issues that may occur when multiple threads are accessing shared, mutable state" Isn't the main thread also a simple thread? If the synchronization is not necessary on main thread methods even when they share objects with other threads why then android studio does not warn about this even when I use annotations?

Comment: EJP say that the main thread is not different and it needs synchronization when required. Now what should I understand?

Comment: @chris No I didn't. I said its synchronization requirements aren't different form other threads'. Do read what I actually wrote.

Comment: @EJP so do the main threads methods need synchronization when required or synchronization on main thread methods is useless?

Comment: @chris **For the sixth time,** *there is nothing magical about the main thread.*  Its synchronization requirements aren't different from other threads'. Is this really so difficult to understand?

Comment: The general case is "this mutable state is accessed by one thread and one thread only" versus "this mutable state is accessed by more than one thread". Whether any of the threads is designated the Main Thread doesn't matter to the underlying issue.

Comment: @Barend I consider the worst case scenario. accessed by any thread.

Comment: @chris No you don't. You are fixated on the main thread, for no apparent reason, and despite having been told time after time that it doesn't make any difference what thread it is.

Comment: Hmm... that very first paragraph of my answer I added at the very end... and it's incorrect. I will be editing the answer a bit more.

Comment: @chris I have updated my answer. I'm frankly out of time now, but I hope this helps. Most modern frameworks handle this issue by avoiding it completely, and there's a good reason for that, it's really complicated stuff. I really recommend the book I mentioned in my answer. It made me a much better programmer.